# How can I refresh the app after each update?

Tags: android, android-studio

The app has a database, but after each update, the new information does not appear in the app, I have to delete the data of the app to see the new info. What can I do? Is there an option to implement a button or something similar? I just want this procedure done within the app, but if there is another way, much better. Is there a way to do it without losing data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide us with your current code and informations about how you are displaying code in order to give you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refresh the Activity after for example having updated data in the database, you can update the View of an item (i.e. TextView ...) through `invalidate ()` or if you use a Fragment perform the `repalce()` of the fragment.